# Number of binary values in chromosone - binomial distribution example

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

There is an example, in short.

You have got $n$ binary values and chromosome $X$ has $k$ values of 1 and $(n-k)$ values of 0. Chromosome $Y$ is made by mutation of $x$, where the mutation is just reverse values in $x$ to $y$, so $y$ has $k$ values of 0 and $(n-k)$ values of 1. And every mutation has the probability of $p$.

Find and Expected Value of the number of values of 1 which has chromosome $Y$.

Please guys, I just need a right distribution of this value. Expected value will be easy. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: This is not clear.  $Y$ has $n-k$ $1's$, there is no probability here.  Or did you omit something?

Comment: @lulu sorry, question is edited

Comment: It isn't clear.  You tell us that $Y$ has $n-k$ $1's$.  Where does probability enter into it?

Comment: As a suggestion:  work an actual example.  Presumably, whatever it is you have in mind is easy to see when $n$ is small, say $n\in \{1,2,3\}$.  Why not work those cases in your post?  Then we'll understand where probability is used (is it in the choice of $k$?  Is it in the mutation itself?  Something else?) and can help with the general case.

Comment: @lulu every reverse of binary value from chromosome $x$ to chromosome $y$ is made with probabilty $p$

Comment: Please edit your post to include worked examples for $n\in \{1,2,3\}$.  Not only will that clarify the question it may also show you the way to answer it.

Comment: Voting to close the question because it isn't clear what you are asking.  If you can, please edit for clarity and to include your efforts.  As previously suggested, a carefully worked example or two for small $n$ will be a big help.